# Cascading - Join two files based on field value

Tags: cascading

I am trying to join two files based on some common field value and get all matched records.

I have two `Tap` for two files reading. i want to join the files and get matched records using `no` `Field`.

How do i join the files and `assemble` the pipes to create `Flow`?

**Sample Code:**

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
AppProps.setApplicationJarClass(properties, Test.class);
FlowConnector flowConnector = new LocalFlowConnector();

Fields custFields = new Fields("no", "name", "city");
FileTap custFileTap = new FileTap(new TextDelimited(custFields,true, ","), "C://Users//Test//cust.txt");

Fields tsctnFields = new Fields("no", "tdate", "tamt");
FileTap tsctnFileTap = new FileTap(new TextDelimited(tsctnFields,true, ","),    "C://Users//Test//tsctn.txt");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build pipes that are connected to your taps, join them, then connect the output pipe to the sink.

```
Tap outTap = new MultiSinkTap(); // just saying, create your own tap
Pipe custFilePipe = new Pipe("custFilePipe");
Pipe tsctnFilePipe = new Pipe("tsctnFilePipe");

Fields groupFields = new Fields("no"); // fields used as joining keys
Pipe outPipe = new CoGroup(custFilePipe, groupFields, tsctnFilePipe, groupFields, new InnerJoin());

// build flow definition
FlowDef flowDef = FlowDef.flowDef().setName("myFlow")
 .addSource(custFilePipe, custFileTap)
 .addSource(tsctnFilePipe, tsctnFileTap)
 .addTailSink(outPipe, outTap);

Flow flow = flowConnector.connect(flowDef); // now you build the flow
flow.complete(); // run flow
```

[Cascading for the Impatient](http://www.cascading.org/category/impatient/) is a good tutorial that I'd recommend to Cascading beginners.